# How do I rotate the petals flat?

Tags: particles

I'm new to blender and just trying to play around with the particle system though I can't seem to figure out how to rotate these petals. I'm sure there's a simple answer. I just want to rotate them flat but changing the phase in the rotation tab doesn't help, it just rotates it around a weird point.

[image]

Comment: share your blend file here to see whats going on.. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: There's a nice video on orienting particles [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t44ssJK3vyw)

Answer (score 1):

If the *Phase* setting isn't rotating your particle correctly, it's very likely that your particle isn't oriented on the correct axis.

Objects used as hair particles do not view Z+ as "up".  They must have a different orientation, for some legacy reason coming from the particle system's beginnings, afaik.

The default particle orientation can be changed in *Object Properties* -> *Relations* -> *Tracking Axis*.  It is +Y by default, changing it to +Z will probably make more sense for most people.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to rotate the object (the initial petal) where the petals are inheriting from, in object mode or even in edit mode if it has modifiers on it.